# Python parsing json data to Netezza table

Tags: python, json, netezza

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Lea",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "hhaa@gma",
    "address": {
      "street": "Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 5",
      "city": "Gwen",
      "zipcode": "3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770",
    "website": "hilde.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Roma",
      "catchPhrase": "net",
      "bs": "markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Er",
    "username": "Ant",
    "email": "Sh",
    "address": {
      "street": "Vis",
      "suite": "89",
      "city": "Wibrugh",
      "zipcode": "905",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-69",
    "website": "ansia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deist",
      "catchPhrase": "contingency",
      "bs": " supply-chains"
    }
  }
]

I am getting this data from webscraping and I would like to store this data into netezza database. Can you Please give me sample code? Do I need to correct Json before? If yes, How would I do it?
And when I am trying to use items iterate in list, I am only getting the last user id details.

Comment: are you sharing actual user data here?

Comment: No But I changed it to make it easy to have just two users now.

Comment: http://dwgeek.com/connecting-netezza-using-python-pyodbc-working-example.html/

Comment: I would like to know how I insert the data into exact key value pair. I am having issue with that. But I am having issue with the insert with the for loop with key value pairs.. Or is there any other way that I can handle it?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import json
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


r=requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.com/users')
data = r.text
print (data)
data = json.loads(data)


conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=dw; PORT=5;DATABASE=SYSTEM; UID=3;PWD=N!;")
cus=conn.cursor()        

for json in data:
    for (k, v) in json.items():
        cus.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (k, v) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')")
        conn.commit()

Comment: Can someone help me with this code? importing the list into netezza?   for json in data: for (k, v) in json.items(): cus.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (k, v) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')")... This is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach, due to better scalability:

1) load the raw txt data into a (temporary) table with the ‘external table’ syntax of Netezza

2) use these functions to parse the Json data into table columns: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-json-table-trs/